# How to extract what I want from string in Python

Tags: string, python-3.3

I have a program in Python 3.3 which has a string which I would like to just get the stuff off the end of. For example "Mary had a little lamb". I would like to just get the text after 'a' in the string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
s =  "Mary had a little lamb"
print(s.split(" a ")[1])
little lamb
print (s[10:])
little lamb`
```

Split on the `a` and get the element after or slice from the `10th` char to the end of the string.

```
s =  'Mary had a very very little lamb'
print(s.split(" a ",1)[1]) 

very very little lamb
```

If you had one of couple of  potential strings:

```
sts = ["Mary had some little lamb","Mary had a little lamb"]
for s in sts:
    if " a " not  in sts:
        print("a is not in this string so the result is {}".format(s.split("had",1)[1]))
    else:
        print("a is in this string so  the result is {}".format(s.split(" a ",1)[1]))
```

If you want only the last two words as a string:

```
sts = ["Mary had some little lamb","Mary had a little lamb"]
for s in sts:
    print(" ".join(s.split()[-2:])) # from second last element to the end
little lamb
little lamb
```

If you have a string with two `" a "` and want to split on just the last:

```
s =  "Mary had a dog and  a little lamb"
print(s.rsplit(" a ",1)[1]) # use rsplit in maxsplit = 1, to only split once
little lamb
```

If you had complicated search patterns then `re` would probably be what you need.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is the beginning of the string (and length of string) won't always be the same. For instance, sometimes it might be 'Mary had a little lamb', and sometimes it might be 'Mary had a very very little lamb'.

Comment: What if sometimes it would be "Mary had some little lamb" and sometimes it would be "Mary had a very very little lamb". Would split still work? And if so how?

Comment: what would you want from that?

Comment: The point is the order and length of the string is randomized.

Comment: there is no `a` in  your second example so what output would you expect?

Comment: Theoretically, I would still expect 'little lamb'.

Comment: The string 'Mary had a little lamb' represents unpredictable input.

Comment: splits on whitespace and gets the last two elements of the list.

Comment: Interesting... I'm still not positive this will work for what I want, though.

Comment: that depends on all the potential cases you may have, only you can decide that, if you only want the last two words in the string then it will work.

Comment: @LukeDinkler have you seen my answer? it might be more what you're thinking of

Answer (score 1):

Using the slice method.

```
result = mystring[start:end]
```

The start is inclusive, the end is exclusive.

```
mystring = "Mary had a little lamb"
newstring = mystring[11:]
print(newstring)
>>> "little lamb"
```

When there isn't a start or end digit that you post, it starts at the very beginning or goes to the very end.

EDIT: Based on your comments from above answer: You could do something like this

```
>>> mystring = "Mary had a very little lamb"
>>> mystring2 = "Mary had little little lamb"
>>> strings = [mystring, mystring2]
>>> for string in strings:
        if string[9] == 'a':
            newstring = string[11:]
        else:
            newstring2 = string[9:]
>>> newstring
'very little lamb'
>>> newstring2
'little little lamb'
```

This is assuming there's always a "Mary had.." at the beginning of your string, and will grab what's after the "a" if there is or isn't one. This isn't the best solution I don't think, but gives you a way to think about it.